# Pandas groupby and then select one row

Tags: python, pandas

I hava pandas dataframe where I have to group by some columns. Most groups in the group by only have one row, but a few have more than one row. For each of these, I only want to keep the row with the earliest date.
I've tried both the `agg` and `filter` functions, but they don't seem to do what I need.

```
def first(df):
        if len(df) > 1:
            return df.ix[df['date'].idxmin()]
        else:
            return df

df.groupby(['id', 'period', 'type').agg(first)
```

Comment: `df.sort_values('date').groupby(['id', 'period', 'type']).first()` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sort by date and then just grab the first row.

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby(['id', 'period', 'type']).first()
```

Answer (score 3):

Could also use `nsmallest()`:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'period', 'type']).apply(lambda g: g.nsmallest(1, "date"))
```

Answer (score 3):

filter `df` with the index of the minimum date.
`idxmin` gets you that index.  Then pass it to `loc`.

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['id', 'period', 'type']).date.idxmin()]
```

---

consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['a', 'q', 'y', '2011-03-31'],
        ['a', 'q', 'y', '2011-05-31'],
        ['a', 'q', 'y', '2011-07-31'],
        ['b', 'q', 'x', '2011-12-31'],
        ['b', 'q', 'x', '2011-01-31'],
        ['b', 'q', 'x', '2011-08-31'],
    ], columns=['id', 'period', 'type', 'date'])
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df

  id period type       date
0  a      q    y 2011-03-31
1  a      q    y 2011-05-31
2  a      q    y 2011-07-31
3  b      q    x 2011-12-31
4  b      q    x 2011-01-31
5  b      q    x 2011-08-31
```

Then

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['id', 'period', 'type']).date.idxmin()]

  id period type       date
0  a      q    y 2011-03-31
4  b      q    x 2011-01-31
```