# pandas groupby date select earliest per day

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
            value            timestamp
0            Fire  2017-10-03 14:33:52
1           Water  2017-10-04 14:33:48
2            Fire  2017-10-04 14:33:45
3            Fire  2017-10-05 14:33:30
4           Water  2017-10-03 14:33:40
5           Water  2017-10-05 14:32:13
6           Water  2017-10-04 14:32:01
7            Fire  2017-10-03 14:31:55
```

I want to group this set by `timestamp` per day and then only select the earliest row per day. For the above example the following should be the result:

```
            value            timestamp
1           Water  2017-10-05 14:32:13
2           Water  2017-10-04 14:32:01
3            Fire  2017-10-03 14:31:55
```

For example, for the day `2017-10-03` there are 3 entries but I only want the earliest on that day.

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348587/pandas-groupby-and-then-select-one-row

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have unique index, you can use `idxmin` on `timestamp` to find out the indices of the minimum *timestamp* and extract them with `loc`:

```
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df.loc[df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.date, as_index=False).timestamp.idxmin()]

#   value             timestamp
#7   Fire   2017-10-03 14:31:55
#6  Water   2017-10-04 14:32:01
#5  Water   2017-10-05 14:32:13
```

Answer (score 4):

**Just Making Sure**

```
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
```

**Solution**

```
d1 = df.sort_values('timestamp')
d1[~d1.timestamp.dt.date.duplicated()]

   value           timestamp
7   Fire 2017-10-03 14:31:55
6  Water 2017-10-04 14:32:01
5  Water 2017-10-05 14:32:13
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `dt.floor` and `head`:

```
df.sort_values('timestamp').groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.floor('D')).head(1)
```

Output:

```
   value           timestamp
7   Fire 2017-10-03 14:31:55
6  Water 2017-10-04 14:32:01
5  Water 2017-10-05 14:32:13
```

Comment: When using the above I get the error: `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`; I then tried to apply the timestamp conversion from @Psidom `pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)` which results in the error `AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'floor'`

Comment: You need to make sure that timestamp is datetiime dtype and you need to still use `.dt` accessor.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.date).apply(lambda x:x[x.timestamp==min(x.timestamp)])
Out[714]: 
              value           timestamp
timestamp                              
2017-10-03 7   Fire 2017-10-03 14:31:55
2017-10-04 6  Water 2017-10-04 14:32:01
2017-10-05 5  Water 2017-10-05 14:32:13
```

Comment: Seems to work but only after I applied the `df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)` first